# get connected monitor(s) details on a Debian system

Tags: linux, debian, monitors, system-information

I am running Debian 11 with GNOME, and realized that getting information about the connected monitor(s) is not that easy (preferably from terminal).

The most promising solution I found was with `read-edid` but it gave me the output that I have put below.

Any ideas about which is the best way of getting information about the monitor, such as model, manufacturer etc?

```
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
Looks like no busses have an EDID. Sorry!
Attempting to use the classical VBE interface

        Performing real mode VBE call
        Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f00 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
        Function unsupported
        Call failed

        VBE version 0
        VBE string at 0x0 "O"

VBE/DDC service about to be called
        Report DDC capabilities

        Performing real mode VBE call
        Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
        Function unsupported
        Call failed

Reading next EDID block

VBE/DDC service about to be called
        Read EDID

        Performing real mode VBE call
        Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x1 cx=0x0
        Function unsupported
        Call failed

The EDID data should not be trusted as the VBE call failed
Error: output block unchanged
I'm sorry nothing was successful. Maybe try some other arguments
if you played with them, or send an email to Matthew Kern <pyrophobicman@gmail.com>.
```

Answer (score 0):

try hwinfo (possibly not installed by default -

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install hwinfo
```

then:

```
# hwinfo --monitor
20: None 00.0: 10002 LCD Monitor                                
  [Created at monitor.125]
  Unique ID: rdCR.N0FAT8Jqir3
  Parent ID: _Znp.b_TacHfrIK6
  Hardware Class: monitor
  Model: "DELL S2415H"
  Vendor: DEL "DELL"
  Device: eisa 0xa0b5 "DELL S2415H"
  Serial ID: "MG4R352S0EWL"
  Resolution: 720x400@70Hz
  Resolution: 640x480@60Hz
  Resolution: 640x480@75Hz
  Resolution: 800x600@60Hz
  Resolution: 800x600@75Hz
  Resolution: 1024x768@60Hz
  Resolution: 1024x768@75Hz
  Resolution: 1280x1024@75Hz
  Resolution: 1152x864@75Hz
  Resolution: 1280x1024@60Hz
  Resolution: 1600x900@60Hz
  Resolution: 1600x1200@60Hz
  Resolution: 1920x1080@60Hz
  Size: 527x296 mm
  Year of Manufacture: 2015
  Week of Manufacture: 9
  Detailed Timings #0:
     Resolution: 1920x1080
     Horizontal: 1920 2008 2052 2200 (+88 +132 +280) +hsync
       Vertical: 1080 1084 1089 1125 (+4 +9 +45) +vsync
    Frequencies: 148.50 MHz, 67.50 kHz, 60.00 Hz
  Driver Info #0:
    Max. Resolution: 1920x1080
    Vert. Sync Range: 56-76 Hz
    Hor. Sync Range: 30-83 kHz
    Bandwidth: 148 MHz
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #17 (VGA compatible controller)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. `hwinfo` and `lshw` were my first attempts, and `hwinfo` has an empty output. That wasn't your case, so it may be the specific hardware. In any case, I believe that there must be a way to get information about any hardware.